# Sort NSArray alphabetically avoiding certain characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I have an NSArray of objects (not NSStrings, but custom objects).  Each object has a value `obj.name`  I know how to sort the NSMutableArray by name as shown below

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
 [array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

However, some of the names start with "The", "A", or "An" all of which I want to skip over to the next word in the name if they appear.  Is there anyway to avoid those three cases and automatically shift to the next word if they appear?

Comment: Your other option is to store the name field a second time, stripped of the "offensive" characters.

Comment: I would agree to Hot Licks. Store an additional sortName in the form of _"Apple, A"_ or _"Apple, The"_ for sorting. That's a simpler and better data design. Maybe there will be more prefixes in the future...

Comment: If these are user entered values, you may want to deal with other languages too since obviously "a", "an", and "the" only apply to English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I dare be contrary to all the answers posted to date, the easiest answer to your literal question would be to implement a getter on your custom class that returned the adjusted string:

```
- (NSString *)canonicalName
{
    if([self.name rangeOfString:@"The "].location == 0)
        return [self.name subStringFromIndex:4];

    // etc, etc
}
```

Then sort by specifying 'canonicalName' to the sort descriptor.

However, you should first consider following the advice in [QA1159](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1159/_index.html) and just using `NSString`'s inherent ability to order itself as per the same rules applied by the Finder, which I think supersets the rules you're trying to implement. So you want to end up comparing strings via `localizedCompare:`, which has been available on iOS since the beginning. You're otherwise pretty much reinventing a non-trivial wheel.

E.g.

```
[array sortUsingComparator:
    ^NSComparisonResult(YourObjectType *obj1, YourObjectType *obj2)
    {
         return [obj1.name localizedCompare:obj2.name];
    }];
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend performing a "sortUsingSelector" which will allow you to write your own sorting method. You would then be able to do the three checks for those conditions and then return the two strings compared.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sortedArrayUsingSelector`. 
Check out [NSArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement your own comparison function, like this (it's very rough, it can be done much more elegantly, but just as a proof of concept):

```
static NSInteger myCompare(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2, void *context)
{
  NSString *str1;
  if ([obj1 hasPrefix:@"A "]) str1 = [obj1 substringFromIndex:2];
  else if ([obj1 hasPrefix:@"An "]) str1 = [obj1 substringFromIndex:3];
  else if ([obj1 hasPrefix:@"The "]) str1 = [obj1 substringFromIndex:4];
  else str1 = obj1;

  NSString *str2;
  if ([obj2 hasPrefix:@"A "]) str2 = [obj2 substringFromIndex:2];
  else if ([obj2 hasPrefix:@"An "]) str2 = [obj2 substringFromIndex:3];
  else if ([obj2 hasPrefix:@"The "]) str2 = [obj2 substringFromIndex:4];
  else str2 = obj2;

  return [str1 compare:str2];
}
```

Then you call `sortedArrayUsingFunction` using it:

```
sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingFunction:myCompare context:NULL];
```